# Scrapy appears to be installed but can't be imported when in the python shell

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, web-scraping, scrapy

I have used the command: sudo pip install scrapy to install scrapy inside of a virtual environment. After having done so, I used the command: scrapy --version
and got the following screen:

[image]

But when I try to import scrapy in the python shell, I get an import error. Is there a specific way to install scrapy within Ubuntu 14.04 besides the way provided in the [docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/ubuntu.html#topics-ubuntu)?

Comment: What is the output of  `which scrapy`?

Comment: @alecxe The output is /usr/local/bin/scrapy

Comment: Ok, do the install without `sudo` when the env is activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this guide: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

```
pip install virtualenv
cd PROJECT_FOLDER
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install scrapy
deactivate #when ready to leave
```

If you are in your virtual environment you should see (venv) next to your command prompt. (I got that in OSX Terminal bash)

As mentioned by others, running:

```
which scrapy
```

will tell you where the binary is. It should be in under the venv folder.

tested on my 2013 Macbook Pro

Comment: I think the problem is that it was installed outside of the venv first by accident so its not able to be installed within the venv subsequently. I think, I will uninstall it on the main system and the install in the venv again